# How to retrieve Alamofire response header for a request

Tags: swift, alamofire

how can I retrieve response headers for a request? Below is a request I make.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, requestUrl, parameters:parameters, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in switch response.result {
        case .Success(let JSON):

            ...

        case .Failure(let error):

            ...

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This code gets response header in Swift 4.2 [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53501929/7707872](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53501929/7707872)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If the response is type of `NSHTTPURLResponse` you can get header from `response.allHeaderFields`.

So when you use Alamofire responseJSON you can access to NSHTTPURLResponse property like this :

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, requestUrl, parameters:parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON {
        response in
        print(response.response?.allHeaderFields)
}
```

As apple documentation says :

> A dictionary containing all the HTTP header fields received as part of the server’s response. By examining this dictionary clients can see the “raw” header information returned by the HTTP server.
>
> The keys in this dictionary are the header field names, as received from the server. See RFC 2616 for a list of commonly used HTTP header fields.

So to get for example a content-type in response header you can access it in that way :

```
if let contentType = response.response?.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"] as? String {
        // use contentType here
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to cast the Content-Type like your code...have anything changed?