# Determine filetype after downloading from url with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, file, alamofire

I scrape a website and find a link to a file that I want to download. The information that I get from the link is the title and a URL to the resource (from a given `<a href>` HTML-element). I use Alamofire to download the resource like this:

```
let fileUrl = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("quicklook.txt")
let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _,_ in return (fileUrl, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories]) }

let request = Alamofire.download(resourceUrl, to: destination).responseData { (response) in
    switch response.result {
    case .failure(let error):
        break
    case .success(let result):
        break
    }
}
```

My issue is that the file that is linked to, could be many different filetypes, such as `.docx`, `.txt`, `.img`, `.pdf`, ect.

Is it possible to determine what file is being downloaded without knowing the pathExtension before hand?

How does safari know what type of content it is downloading, when downloading a resource from a link?

Answer (score 0):

The response header contains a [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) property that is used to pass the type for the data.

You should be able to get the Response Header from alamofire and check the content type.

Edit: looks like the accepted answer here is what you might want [How to retrieve Alamofire response header for a request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523557/how-to-retrieve-alamofire-response-header-for-a-request)