# Alamofire get size of url before download

Tags: alamofire

How would I implement a head request using alamofire to get the size of the resource pointed to by the url BEFORE anything is downloaded?

If I use the head method (enum of Alamofire) would the response somewhere contain the content-length?

Comment: HEAD returns headers without the body; use AF to parse the headers the way you normally would and check for content length.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get response headers when using Alamofire in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923870/how-to-get-response-headers-when-using-alamofire-in-swift)